# Python Dict: Keep first column , and make the rest as nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Given the following dict:

```
mydict={'id': '123', 'name': 'Bob', 'age': '30','city': 'LA'}
```

I would like to transform this dictionary into a nested dict, where "id" key is kept, but all other (arbitary) keys are then packed into a nested dict. Hence the output should be like:

```
nestdict={'id':'123','data':{'name': 'Bob', 'age': '30','city': 'LA'}}
```

What I have tried was using dict.pop but this returns a list , and also using `defaultdict` from collections, but this did not work.

```
from collections import defaultdict
nestdict = defaultdict(dict)
nestdict[mydict['id']] = mydict[['name'],['age'],['city']]
nestdict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mutate the original `mydict`,

```
>>> mydict = {'id': '123', 'name': 'Bob', 'age': '30','city': 'LA'}
>>> d = {'id': mydict['id'], 'data': {k: v for k, v in mydict.items() if k != "id"}}
{'id': '123', 'data': {'name': 'Bob', 'age': '30', 'city': 'LA'}}
```

If mutating `mydict` (since we pop out `id`) is OK,

```
>>> mydict = {'id': '123', 'name': 'Bob', 'age': '30','city': 'LA'}
>>> d = {'id': mydict.pop('id'), 'data': mydict}
{'id': '123', 'data': {'name': 'Bob', 'age': '30', 'city': 'LA'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of your dictionary to preserve the original one:

```
temp_dict = mydict.copy()
temp_dict.pop('id')
nested_dict = {'id': mydict['id'], 'data': temp_dict}
print(nested_dict)
```

The output:

```
{'id': '123', 'data': {'name': 'Bob', 'age': '30', 'city': 'LA'}}
```